# Netbeans with Chrome integration on HTML5 project

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans, google-chrome-extension, netbeans-7

I have successfully installed both netbeans and the chrome extension for doing html/css/js work. It appears to work for the most part but I've seen some questionable activity that is... "limiting".

Netbeans > Chrome seems like a fragile interaction. In netbeans, I select run file, and the page opens in chrome *always* in a new window (is that right?). Part of the marketing here is that you're supposed to be able to edit the css without having to constantly go to the browser and reload. But in netbeans, when I go to the tab of the css file (in the same project), the chrome page bombs with the Dead Folder icon and the text "Something went wrong while displaying this webpage".

What's supposed to be the process here? It seems to work in principle, but not in practice.

***[update]***

I had also had the addon problem that if I did Run Main Project while looking at the css file, it would show the css file as if it were the main html file. After setting chrome as the default browser, this action shows the actual main html file. At that point, making any change to the css file, any typing at all, will bomb the chrome page.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html).

Once you run a page/project in Chrome with NetBeans integration, in NetBeans there is a  window CSS Styles and slightly different Navigator (in 7.3). Now in browser you can start Inspect mode (for instance right click on NetBeans logo in omnibar and check "Inspect in NetBeans mode") and then you can for instance click on elements in browser and if you do that, the CSS Styles window in IDE shows all css properties and rules applied to selected element. You can edit CSS from either CSS Styles or by plain old editing of CSS file in NetBeans. In both cases, changes are visible in Chrome without any reload (without even saving the css file). And you can also use JavaScript debugger in NetBeans.

I don't know what do you mean by "chrome page bombs", but page cannot be debugged by 2 "debuggers" at the same time in Chrome - so you can either use NetBeans or Chrome Developer tools.

There are many new features in the upcoming NetBeans 7.4 (you can download 7.4 Beta from netbeans.org). You can try it as well.

Comment: I clarified what 'bomb' means in the op. Thanks for responding. I am however aware of how it's supposed to work. As stated in the op "You can edit CSS ... by plain old editing of CSS file in NetBeans." causes the chrome web page to... bomb, die, something... (i hesitate to say crash as that implies whole-app behaviour.) Bottom line is that I am unable to use it in the way it appears to have been intended.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see it as well. My guess is Chrome just updated to recent version and it somehow breaks something (because I have also Chromium Version 29.0.1538.0 (206004) and it works just fine). I reported it to NetBeans as issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234848 , you can see progress there. Thank you for noticing this

Comment: Ah good. And thanks for the report. Do you think this would also affect my ability to use chromium variants instead of chrome? I could install the plugin, but even tho it's set as my primary browser, it wouldn't catch the link from netbeans.

Comment: Using Chromium should work until but I think eventually Chromium gets updated to the same version as Chrome. But generally speaking, the inspection works the same way in Chrome and Chromium